# How can I disable links on two finger touch on mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem here 
In my website header should be show and hide with two finger tap in mobile.

now when I taped with my two finger on body if the  element was here and I tapped on it, website went to the link.

I want disable links on two finger tap and then show and hide header div.

I used Jquery mobile library

```
 $('body').bind('taptwo', function () {
            $("#header").toggle();
        });
```

Comment: Do you have some code for the `taptwo` event? How You implemented it?

Comment: @deblocker add jgestures library and you can use that event